# Could't load a pre-trained resnet pb file from the official website of Tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I downloaded a pre-trained resnet pb file from
  http://download.tensorflow.org/models/official/resnet_v1_imagenet_savedmodel.tar.gz

And when I tried to import it to the graph by the following code

```
tf.Graph().as_default():

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(path, 'rb') as file:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

        graph_def.ParseFromString(file.read())

        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')`
```

I got the error

```
    graph_def.ParseFromString(file.read())
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\message.py", line 185, in
 ParseFromString
    self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.p
y", line 1083, in MergeFromString
    if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.p
y", line 1120, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", lin
e 633, in DecodeField
    if value._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.p
y", line 1120, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", lin
e 612, in DecodeRepeatedField
    if value.add()._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.p
y", line 1120, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", lin
e 743, in DecodeMap
    if submsg._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.p
y", line 1109, in InternalParse
    new_pos = local_SkipField(buffer, new_pos, end, tag_bytes)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", lin
e 850, in SkipField
    return WIRETYPE_TO_SKIPPER[wire_type](buffer, pos, end)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", lin
e 799, in _SkipGroup
    new_pos = SkipField(buffer, pos, end, tag_bytes)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", lin
e 850, in SkipField
    return WIRETYPE_TO_SKIPPER[wire_type](buffer, pos, end)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", lin
e 814, in _SkipFixed32
    raise _DecodeError('Truncated message.')
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message.
```

'path' is the pb file.

Comment: It says Truncated message, it might be your download was corrupted or wasn't decompressed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the pb file from http://download.tensorflow.org/models/official/resnet_v1_imagenet_savedmodel.tar.gz is only 806KB. So it might be a graph file without weights